# JS is working in JSFiddle not in Real File

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

Dear I checked all the question realates to the subject, but JSfiddle is not working in the actual file. JSFIDDLE is on http://jsfiddle.net/Qac6J/1/

Below is my code, Please let me know what is the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="qtip/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css" />


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        $('.content').hide();
        $('.' + $(this).data('rel')).show();
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.content {
    display: none;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<form id='group'>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-micro-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-micro-desktop" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-mini-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-mini-desktop" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-maxi-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-maxi-desktop" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-mega-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-mega-desktop" />
    </label>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-mega-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-mega-desktop" />
    </label>
</form>

<div class="billpay-internet-add-ons">
    <div class="sim-micro-desktop content">sim-micro</div>
    <div class="sim-mini-desktop content">sim-mini</div>
    <div class="sim-maxi-desktop content">sim-maxi</div>
    <div class="sim-mega-desktop content">sim-mega</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the link to your CSS correct? As in you are getting the CSS on the page right?

Comment: jquery is not loading in your page

Comment: I check the previsous responses and I kept it here.. Do i have to remove it ?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, you probably have a mistake in getting the jQuery file.  Are you sure it's not an absolute path that requires a / to be put in front of the file path?

Comment: are you getting errors in your Firebug console when you run it?

Comment: Igor, yes its not loading, what is the reason on this ? ?

Comment: Your link to jQuery is wrong. Use for example:

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I am not getting any errors, I used the js and styles links from stack overflow questions

Comment: try to use jquery cdn and check it.If it works the edit you script src link.

Comment: A few quick points. **1** There should only be 1 `<head>` element in the document. **2** The `<style>` and `<link>` tags should be inside the head. **3** the `<script>` tags should be in the `<head>` or the `<body>`. Try a HTML validator on your code! Link: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @user3300202, try replacing your script that gets jQuery with the following :    `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`   And see if that makes your code work.

Comment: Thanks enhzflep, i removed the head, i a missed, but the result is same

Comment: @Leo: Why is it wrong to link to a local file?

Comment: @FelixKling, if you use Google's jQuery instead then there is a good chance that jQuery is in the cache already.

Comment: @Leo: Sure, but that doesn't make it *wrong* to use a local copy (as in, it doesn't work with a local jQuery copy).

Comment: Of course you can use a local copy if you want to, @FelixKling. I just assumed that was the problem since it looked to me like your example worked if I just changed the jQuery-link.

Comment: @Leo: My example? I think you confuse me with the OP ;)

Comment: You are right, @FelixKling. ;-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Copy and paste the below code it will work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.trigger').click(function() {
        $('.content').hide();
        $('.' + $(this).data('rel')).show();
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.content {
    display: none;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<form id='group'>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-micro-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-micro-desktop" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-mini-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-mini-desktop" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-maxi-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-maxi-desktop" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-mega-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-mega-desktop" />
    </label>
        <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-mega-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-mega-desktop" />
    </label>
</form>

<div class="billpay-internet-add-ons">
    <div class="sim-micro-desktop content">sim-micro</div>
    <div class="sim-mini-desktop content">sim-mini</div>
    <div class="sim-maxi-desktop content">sim-maxi</div>
    <div class="sim-mega-desktop content">sim-mega</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @poster, I would consider adding why this particular edit works (or at least describe what you changed), as opposed to just saying "copy this", so this question can be helpful to future users with similar problems.

Comment: This is definitely not a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

jquery file path may be a problem ,so  use the jQuery CDN

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

and the data-* attributes are new in HTML5. so try to use  declaration as  `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I replaced <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> with <!DOCTYPE html> and the JS lines its working fine thank you. But this will open in all browsers ?? DW default enter the link.

Comment: it will open in all browser

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Manoj's answer, the problem is most definitely because you specified an incorrect filepath, since the CDN version fixed your problem.

If you like, you can use the CDN version that Manoj provided, but keep in mind if you would like to include a local copy, that is always an option.

In your head, you have:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="qtip/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>`

In order for this to work, your filetree would need to look like this

[image]

this is because you are specifying a **relative path** from your document, so any folder requested will start out in the same folder as the html file it is included in.  I'm willing to be this is **not** the case with your server, and that you have the `qtip` folder somewhere else

In order to set up an **absolute path** you should lead your file location with a `/` to specify a root folder to start from.

For instance, if you had a setup like the following,

[image]

you would get the jquery file through an absolute path with `/qtip/jquery-2.0.3.min.js`
This is a good practise to get into, especially when naming commonly used files like jquery, so you don't need to specify a different path for each html document.